# Why are there no site traffic statistics from before February 2018?

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred

I was looking at the [site analytics page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics), and noticed there were no site traffic statistics (as opposed to question, answer and vote tallies) from before February 2018; or rather, all values show up as 0's. Were these statistics not collected? That seems weird... is it some kind of retrieval script glitch maybe?

[image]

Comment: I don't have the reputation to check it myself, but are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @Filnor: Nope, I don't see any errors there (using FF 52.9.0).

Comment: Strangely, between the 24th of January and the 7th of February there is _some_ traffic recorded. Less than 3.5k page views. Stats then jump up in to the millions on February 8th. Perhaps integration testing before rollout?

Comment: @Turnip: I'm guessing that collection started midweek. Also, you've posted that chart here, but access is restricted to high-rep users. Obviously I don't mind personally, but please make sure we're not breaking the rules with this edit.

Comment: [status-deferred] known issue (to staff) but may not be fixed. That's all I know

Comment: @SamuelLiew: I'm more interested in the reason than in a fix... you write this is a known issue - what's the issue?

Comment: @einpoklum That is why I removed the figures before posting the image.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Sounds omnious... do you think you could get someone from the staff to answer/comment here?

Comment: @einpoklum This MSE post seems to be the official response on the situation https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989

Comment: @SamuelLiew: That looks like it might be a separate issue (figures going down to 0 rather than up from 0), but I suppose the cause might be the same. Still, not making stats available for 6 months seems pretty strange; all posts and comments on that page seem to have been made in the first several days after that issue was reported.